# tutorial on windows service and client?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, service, client

I am trying to create an application that can run as a service and another program to communicate with it (client)

i can find plenty of sample code about services but nothing about programs that interact with services

can someone please link some examples?

Comment: Like a program that listens on a port number for incoming connections, or something more abstract, like a web service client/server setup?

Comment: no the service will run on the computer in the software configuration management. i want the client to send messages to the service and the service just echoes them back

Comment: When you say service do you mean something specific like a Windows Service or are you being generic meaning some program that just provides a service.

Comment: yes a windows service

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could and maybe should use TCP sockets.  Or at least that would be the easiest and most straight forward.

Alternatively since it sounds like both client and service are on the same computer you could use some form of IPC (interprocess communication).  So depending on your OS you may decide to use IPC instead.